# СEvent::SendImmediate или СEvent::Send - что правильнее использовать для форм обратной связи?

Tags: битрикс

СEvent::SendImmediate или СEvent::Send
Какой функцией предпочтительнее пользоваться для форм обратной связи и почему?

Answer (score 0):

если менеджеру то СEvent::Send она исполняеться на агентах, соответствено меньше нагружает публичную часть, если письмо пользователю то СEvent::SendImmediate, чтоб оно отпрвилось сразу